# Storing Java Double Infinity and NaN values to MS SQL 2008 database

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, double, infinity

In our business logic we have to handle positive and negative `Double.Infinity` values as well as `Double.NaN` values.

We have to store these values into Microsot SQL Server 2008 database. The problem is that Microsot SQL Server doesn't support infinity or nan values. ([Problem description for SQL Server 2005](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/239674/storing-ieee-754-floats-in-sql-server-2005-nan-infinity), also applicable for MS SQL Server 2008).

We are using Hibernate 3.6.7 as our JPA implementation and Microsoft's sqljdbc4 driver version 4.0.2206.100.

We have tried to solve this issue by setting JPA entity's column definition to VARCHAR like this

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)")
private Double foo;
```

This does not seem to have any effect, even though column definition is properly changed to VARCHAR in the database. It seems that the infinity value is caught in JDBC driver's validation since we get the following stacktrace when trying to INSERT `Double.Infinity` value:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The incoming tabular data  stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 79 more
```

Any ideas how to work around this issue are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple workaround for this issue:
Use `String` for field type and do the conversion in getters and setters.
This way you don't have to change your business logic and the actual transformation logic is encapsulated nicely.

```
// Column definition is not a necessity here
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)")
private String foo;

public Double getFoo() {
    return this.foo != null ? Double.valueOf(this.foo) : null;
}

public void setFoo(Double d) {
    this.foo = d != null ? d.toString() : null;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a propper workaround for the problem. Only limitation is that since the value is as VARCHAR in the database, you might not be able to perform calculations for the values in SQL.